# Program to Output list of Gmail Subject/From not working

Tags: python

I am trying to simply output the FROM and SUBJECT fields from each email in my inbox.
I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out so I'm throwing it over the fence in hopes of some help.

The login part seems to work fine, (gmail 2FA) its just processing the results that doesn't seem to be working. Nothing is output when there should be.  I believe it has something to do with the following line:  *if isinstance(response_part, tuple)* 
Why is it looking for a tuple?

I'm too new to python to know what the issue might be.

Can someone let me what might be wrong with my code and how it might be corrected?
I got this code snippet from:

[This link](https://medium.com/@sdoshi579/to-read-emails-and-download-attachments-in-python-6d7d6b60269)

```
import imaplib
import base64
import os
import email

email_user = input('Email: ')
email_pass = input('Password: ')

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
mail.login(email_user, email_pass)
mail.select('Inbox')

type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
mail_ids = data[0]
id_list = mail_ids.split()

for response_part in data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1].decode('utf-8'))
            email_subject = msg['subject']
            email_from = msg['from']
            print('From : ' + email_from + '\n')
            print('Subject : ' + email_subject + '\n')
            print(msg.get_payload(decode=True))
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Thanks for taking my call.  It just ends without anything being output. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution online and thought I would share in case it helps someone down the line.  Thanks for helping out.

```
import imaplib
import base64
import os
import email

email_user = input('Email: ')
email_pass = input('Password: ')

def extract_body(payload):
    if isinstance(payload,str):
        return payload
    else:
        return '\n'.join([extract_body(part.get_payload()) for part in payload])

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
conn.login(email_user, email_pass)
conn.select('"1. Alerts"')
typ, data = conn.search(None, 'ALL')
try:
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, msg_data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        for response_part in msg_data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
                gmail_subj =msg['subject']                   
                print(gmail_subj)
                gmail_from=msg['from']                   
                print(gmail_from)
                payload=msg.get_payload()
                # body=extract_body(payload)
                # print(body)
        typ, response = conn.store(num, '+FLAGS', r'(\Seen)')
finally:
    try:
        conn.close()
    except:
        pass
    conn.logout()
```